# IPMI: LAN Parameter Data does not match

Tags: ipmi, supermicro, ipmitool, bmc

I have a SupoerMicro board with ipmi, where I have some problems in communication using the LAN channel.

The server is running PFsense (netbsd) and I can sendt commands to the local ipmi controller by using IPMI tool. 
In the beginning I was able to set parameters, but at one point it hangs, and in some way got out of sync.

```
lan print 1
```

```
Set in Progress         : Set Complete
Auth Type Support       : NONE MD2 MD5 PASSWORD
Auth Type Enable        : Callback : MD2 MD5 PASSWORD
                        : User     : MD2 MD5 PASSWORD
                        : Operator : MD2 MD5 PASSWORD
                        : Admin    : MD2 MD5 PASSWORD
                        : OEM      : MD2 MD5 PASSWORD
IP Address Source       : Static
IP Address              : 0.0.0.0
Subnet Mask             : 0.0.0.0
MAC Address             : 00:00:00:00:00:00
SNMP Community String   : public
IP Header               : TTL=0x00 Flags=0x00 Precedence=0x00 TOS=0x00
BMC ARP Control         : ARP Responses Enabled, Gratuitous ARP Disabled
Default Gateway IP      : 0.0.0.0
Default Gateway MAC     : 00:08:74:ef:76:81
Backup Gateway IP       : 0.0.0.0
Backup Gateway MAC      : 00:00:00:00:00:00
802.1q VLAN ID          : 40
802.1q VLAN Priority    : 0
RMCP+ Cipher Suites     : 0,1,2,3,6,7,8,11,12
Cipher Suite Priv Max   : aaaaXXaaaXXaaXX
                        :     X=Cipher Suite Unused
                        :     c=CALLBACK
                        :     u=USER
                        :     o=OPERATOR
                        :     a=ADMIN
                        :     O=OEM
```

I can with out problems set the SNMP Community string or the VLAN ID, but I can't set the vlan to off or setting IP Adress, Subnet Mask.

When trying I get this error:

```
LAN Parameter Data does not match!  Write may have failed.
```

I have tried a bmc cold reboot / warm reboot and tried so setting the lan mode using raw parameters

```
X8 ATEN 
to get lan mode 
ipmicfg -raw 0x30 0x70 0x0c 0 
to set lan mode dedicated 
ipmicfg -raw 0x30 0x70 0x0c 1 1 0 
to set lan mode onboard/shared 
ipmicfg -raw 0x30 0x70 0x0c 1 1 1 
to set lan mode failover 
ipmicfg -raw 0x30 0x70 0x0c 1 1 2
```

But nothing helps.

It could be related to this question, [Supermicro IPMI no network](https://serverfault.com/questions/373799/supermicro-ipmi-no-network), but he got no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was an old firmware on the supermicro board. After upgrading the hardware, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

The error `LAN Parameter Data does not match!  Write may have failed.` happens due to prohibited write/change of IPMI/BMC parameters.

The prohibition applied when in Section `[LANCHANNELS]` the parameter `LANFailOver` equals enable. To be able to change network settings of IPMI, this parameter should be set to disable to the time of change. Here is how to do that correctly:

```
syscfg /lfo disable
ipmitool lan set 1 access off
ipmitool lan set 1 ipsrc dhcp
ipmitool lan set 1 access on
syscfg /lfo enable
```

This example changes the IP source to DHCP. Other settings can be added too.

Interesting: the reason Firmware upgrade helped Lauer to solve the issue seems in LanFailover disabled by default in that particular version of the firmware.

`syscfg` is a free tool to be downloaded and used.

Answer (score 0):

I got this when trying to disable the default gateway by running

```
ipmitool lan set 1 defgw ipaddr 0.0.0.0
```

This worked on other machines, but on that particular one I got the "LAN Parameter Data does not match!  Write may have failed." error. The machine had an old X9SCL board with an old BMC firmware version 1.86.

As a workaround I set the default gateway to the machine's own IP address instead.

Once the firmware was updated to 3.52 the above command worked. (This update also fixed a "Command not supported in present state" error when trying to change a user's name.)

**Edit:** on a X11SPI-TF a default gateway of 0.0.0.0 failed even with the latest BMC firmware version (1.69). Using the machine's own IP worked.